# How to clear a complex Array and add an object to it in breeze?

Tags: breeze

So I have an object model declared as such:

```
helper.addComplexType
  name: "Shift"
  dataProperties:
    end_time: "int"
    start_time: "int"
    earliest_in: "int"
    earliest_out: "int"
    latest_in: "int"
    latest_out: "int"
    in_early: "bool"
    in_late: "bool"
    out_early: "bool"
    out_late: "bool"

helper.addType
  name: 'DaySchedule'
  apiVersion: 3
  dataProperties:
    uid: "uid"
    employee_id: "int"
    day: "string"
    shifts:
      complexType: "Shift"
      hasMany: true
  navigationProperties:
    employee:
      type: "Employee"
      assoc: "DayScheduleEmployee"
      key: ["employee_id"]
```

Now I have some code that changes one of these entities and then saves it back to the server...

```
shiftType = entityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Shift");
shift = shiftType.createInstance
  start_time: moment(@start_time).unix()
  end_time: moment(@end_time).unix()
schedule.shifts.splice -1
schedule.shifts.push shift
entityManager.saveChanges()
```

However, when I go to save this to the server, the "shift" on the other side ends up with no data values.  This appears to be coming from, entityManager.helper.unwrapChangedValues, which is returning an empty object for this complex entity.   Am I missing something in creating this complex object and then attaching it to the entity it is associated with?

EDIT:  This seems to be a problem with the way breeze internally unwraps arrays.

https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/issues/4